DAX Measure to Calculate Previous Year Values for Each Year in Power BI
I'm trying to create a DAX measure in Power BI that will calculate the value for the previous year based on each year present in my table. I want to create a list that shows the value for each year and its corresponding value from the previous year.
The problem is that the final result I get only shows the sum value but without the most recent year.
Previous Year Purchasing Power = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Fact_Index[Purchasing Power Index]),
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Fact_Index[Date])
)



SAMPLE DATA



Year
Purchasing Power Index
Previous Purchasing Power Index




2014
100



2015
200



2016
300



SUM
600
300



THE RESULT I WANNA GET



Year
Purchasing Power Index
Previous Purchasing Power Index




2014
100



2015
200
100


2016
300
200


SUM
600
300




you need to create a date table and try below DAX
Previous Year Purchasing Power = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Fact_Index[Purchasing Power Index]),
    DATEADD(DATE[date],-1,year)
)

DATEADD

I haven't implemented your DAX formula, but to create a date table was a great help. It was enough that it started to work. Many thanks Ryan!
